# How to implement the layer control of google map minimap in ionic framework?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework

I need to integrate my camera function and google map function in an ionic project. Currently, I toggled between these two functions by switching to different tabs. However, I want to add a feature that can toggle between these two mode through a minimap. Is there any built-in functions that can help me with this feature?

Here is what google did to switch the view between google earth and google map:
[google minimap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ALv1.png)

Leaflet has it's open source implementation, I might learn from this:
[Leaflet minimap layer control](https://github.com/jieter/Leaflet.layerscontrol-minimap)

Comment: use plugins, show what you do

Comment: I have google map plugin installed, but it seems like they didn't provide the  doc for minimap control.

Comment: Yes, it is cordova plugin.

Comment: https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/issues/844#issuecomment-200467799 did u see this

Comment: It's sort of different from what I'm working on. I have a tab which allows user to turn on the camera live stream and record the camera location, the other tab is simply adding markers on google map currently. Instead of using tabs to switch the view, I want to implement a minimap at the bottom left of the screen to do the same thing. I updated the question, you can check it again.

Comment: https://github.com/jieter/Leaflet.layerscontrol-minimap I might just learn from this.

Comment: create `div` minimap and inside make a `button` and link to this feature, and in next feature link to another feature, see on your tabs' links